# Isn't state observable (state$) of redux-observable v1 an antipattern of redux's unidirectional data flow?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-observable

From my understanding, redux is strictly unidirectional data flow.

```
actions (data in) -> store updates (reducer) -> react render (data flow ends here)
```

With action observable it's still unidirectional

```
 actions -> state changes -> react render
 ^    |
 |    |
epics<-
```

However, with state observable, data flows back

```
actions -> state changes -> react render
   ^          |
   |          |
   epics <----
```

As a result, it may causes infinite data flows when

- `epicA` subscribed to change of `stateA` changes `stateB` and
- `epicB` subscribed to change of `stateB` changes `stateA`.

Especially when app grows, it becomes harder and harder to monitor the state changes and debug, which is the exact issue that unidirectional data flow tries to solve.

Am I having any misunderstandings anywhere?

---

To clarify my question, isn't dispatching actions with state observable an antipattern of redux's unidirectional data flow?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The main idea of "unidirectional data flow" is that random other parts of the application can't (or aren't allowed) to change these pieces of data themselves.  Instead, a part of the application that owns that data is responsible for all changes, whether it be a Redux store or a stateful React component.

In the specific example you describe, all of the state updates are still being caused by actions dispatched to the Redux store, and any state update can be traced to a dispatched action and a reducer function that provided the updated state.

Now, yes, complex async logic *can* become tangled, but that's a separate question than the concept of "unidirectional data flow".

Comment: To add, action$ doesn't provide anything you couldn't have done before it was introduced (but with more code). In a nutshell it's almost identical to `action$.map(() => store.getState()).distinctUntilChanged()`. It's a pattern some have found useful, but it absolutely can be abused or be the source of hard to follow dataflow graphs

Comment: I definitely do want to encourage you to create a ticket if you have compelling real world examples that show it's a bad idea cause we haven't received much of any negative feedback, which was actually pretty surprising.

Comment: In my mind, unidirectional data flow has two key points.
I have no doubt about that actions are supposed to be the only entry point of all data and my example still follow it.

However the other key part is that data shouldn't flow back. "State change fires an action to change the state" sounds odd. Why don't just make the state changes in one time?  Also I think actions should only comes from user event (click/input/...) or page event (page load/timer/...). Or api responses followed to those user and page events.

Comment: @jayphelps I don't have a real world example at the moment. We recently just migrated to redux-observable v1 and noticed this new state observable. I'm just not sure if it's a good pattern/practice to create actions that subscribed to the state observable for my concerns above. Would like to hear how other people are using it and if they have the same concerns as mine.

Comment: @jayphelps The autosave example given on [redux-observable site](https://redux-observable.js.org/MIGRATION.html) is a good show case of the possible usage of state observable. It's cool. But I see the danger of doing it. If that's allowed, people who creates new action/reducer must be extremely cautious about what state changes it makes. Without going through every existing epics defined, they have no ideas of what side effects the new action/reducer may cause. It will soon become a nightmare. In that case, I'd rather choose to listen to all the possible actions that could change the state.

Comment: "Also I think actions should only comes from user event (click/input/...) or page event" state does not update without one of these things, remember it doesn't give you anything you didn't already have

Comment: Just wanna make sure that was clear :) but I do share your concern

Comment: Or, to put it another way: you could already check for state changes and dispatch actions even without RxJS,  in a middleware, store subscription callback, or a React component's `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: @markerikson Exactly. But I believe dispatching actions in `componentDidUpdate` is evil - [one of should not do] (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate). We have once done this when we first started using react and redux and got ourselves in troubles soon and moved us away from it since. As you said, dispatching actions using state observable does the exact same thing.

Comment: With the introduction of state observable and the autosave example given on the site, I feel like it's encouraging people to do a danger thing. Or at least we should warn people about it.

Comment: I should clarify my question, "Isn't dispatching actions using state observable an antipattern?"

Comment: I wouldn't say it always is, no.  It's maybe not always the best choice, but I'm sure there are situations where it's a reasonable thing to do.